# Infopath browser support

Tags: 2010, infopath, browser-compatibility

In our company, we have two big SharePoint 2010 farms, one is internet-facing, the other one is intra-net facing. Because we are planning to host all of our internet facing sites (30+), intranet, extranet, applications on this platform, we created a lot of guidance/rules. This should prevent different developers from reinventing the wheel, doing things that we don't want and help them with choices they have to make based on requirements.

One of those guidance documents that we want to introduce, is about the use of infoPath. according to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526.aspx the browser support is kind of limited. It only lists IE7-IE9 32bit as full support, IE7-IE9 64bit, firefox 3.6 and safari with limited support. All other browsers are not supported. quote:

> **Not supported**   If a Web browser is not listed, it is not supported. For example, older Web browsers — such as Internet Explorer 5.01, Internet Explorer 5.5x, Internet Explorer for Macintosh, and versions of third-party Web browsers that are earlier than the ones listed — are not supported.

Please note that popular browsers as chrome and opera are neither supported. I tested some basic functions of infopath in some 'not supported browsers' (for example chrome, opera) and I can conclude that all those browsers are functioning correctly.

my question: can anyone tell me what i can and can't do when I want to create forms for my *public facing websites* and want to be sure that those forms won't break in those not supported browsers? This really speeds up our development time (read, reduces costs) and prevents us from building custom webparts, because they all cause the whole hassle of all required tests (not limited to load, performance, acceptance, security, you name it ;)), reviews, buildtime, deployments and so on.

Answer (score 1):

At first, if MS says that something is not supported it does *not* necessarily mean that it won't work, but just that they havn't tested it.

As far as I know "normal" (meaning: simple) control in InfoPath should work with lots of browsers. However, there might be issue with Active-X components come into play. This said, I suggest you test for controls like file attachement, people picker and date/time picker in your forms.

Maybe other people found a list of things that do not work properly?

Comment: I already knew about the "not supported" thingy. "The list of things" is exactly what I am looking for ;)